# Dnsmaq conflicts with regular internet connetion (ethernet)

Tags: django, linux-mint, dnsmasq, hostapd

i have a django server running on a desktop computer(linuxmint 18.3 64 bits), i use hostapd and dnsmasq to serve the django site in a local area via wifi(a room).
desktop also have a regular Internet connection over Ethernet cable.(Internet access is NOT shared over wifi.)
however while dnsmasq is running, the desktop is unable to connect to the Internet. i need to both serve the django site over wifi and been able to access the Internet at the same time.
here are my configurations

cat dnsmasq.conf

```
except-interface=enp0s25
except-interface=lo
interface=wlp48s0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.250,12h
dhcp-option=3,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.1
server=8.8.8.8
#log-queries
#log-dhcp
address=/#/10.0.0.1

listen-address=10.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
```

cat hostapd.conf

```
ap_isolate=1
interface=wlp48s0
#driver=nl80211
ssid=LOCALACCESSPOINT
channel=6#0 #1

auth_algs=1           # 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
wpa=2                 # WPA2 only
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=123456789
```

also run a service every boot

cat set_ip.service

```
[Unit]
Description=asignar ip a la tarjeta wifi
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/mint/set_ip.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

cat set_ip.sh

```
ifconfig wlp48s0 down
sleep 2
ifconfig wlp48s0 10.0.0.1 up
sleep 4
systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
iptables -i wlp48s0  -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
iptables -i wlp48s0 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

as soon as i call sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq.service im able to browse the Internet again.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: after some test i find that commenting the line address=/#/10.0.0.1 fix the connections issues, 
but that means users would have to type the ip 10.0.0.1 , which scare the users

Comment: FIXED. only change one line: address=/*/10.0.0.1 with a "*"